# Visitor Pattern accept is not recognizing the class of the object

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I want to use the visitor pattern to implement a tree. So I made a main class `Node` and other classes that extends that class (for example `Node1`, `Node2`, `Node3`). In `Node` I have a String and an `ArrayList` of `Nodes` which is a list of children of that node. So I implemented a visitor with 3 functions `visit(Node1 x)`, ... and in `main` I want to call accept of every node:

```
SomeVisitor v = new SomeVisitor();
Node n = makeTree();
Iterator<? extends Node> it = n.children.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next().getClass());

    it.next.accept(v); 
}
```

this doesn't work because even though `.getClass` returns a specific class 
I mean Node 1 , 2 or 3 and the error I get is that is `it.next` is a type 
node but I don't have any node object in my tree , and I didn't implement 
`visit(Node)` just `visit(Node 1,2,3)`

Comment: You have a bug in the bit of code you posted: you are calling `it.next()` twice in the same iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Check the description of the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The accept method should be declared in the base class, and each subclass should override it by calling back the appropriate visit method:

```
public abstract class Node {
    public abstract void accept(Visitor v); 
}

public class Node1 extends Node {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this); // calls visit(Node1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to use the visitor pattern, which is not what you appear to be doing.

> I didn't implement visit(Node) just visit(Node 1,2,3)

This is your problem.  You have to implement the same interface with the same method which what you call.

Also you need to write it as

```
v.visit(it.next());
```

@JB Nizet's solution is similar, but I think its simpler to write the code in the manner it needs to be called from the start.

Comment: Nope. The accept method should be in the base Node class. But there should be one visit method per type of subclass. No need for visit(Node), unless several subclass want to be visited in a common, generic way.

Comment: Because each subclass overrides the accept method. See my answer and the wikipedia link. The visit methods could even have different names: visitNode1, visitNode2, visitNode3. Each subclass decides which visit method to call when the visitor asks to accept a visit.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the whole point of polymorphism.  Why write separate methods when structuring the calls correctly avoids the need to do this?

Comment: Suppose you have a list of Documents. Each document can be printed, sent and displayed, each in a specific way. It's not always a good idea to give all these responsibilities to the Document class (and subclasses). So, you'll create a Printer, a Sender and a Displayer. Instead of letting the Printer test which kind of Document each element of the list is (using instanceof), you just implement N print() methods (one per kind of Document), and let each document call the appropriate one. And since you do the same thing for the Sender, you make them implement a common Visitor interface.

Comment: i agree that the visitor pattern is not appropriate in all cases because you cannot place all the code in either the visitor or the visited.

Comment: So I implement in the Node class an accept method 

    public void accept(Visitor v){
      v.visit(this); // but this won't work if I don't implement in the visitor
                                    visit(Node) ? so what should I do ? 
    
     }
thanks for your answers

Comment: You need to implement Vistor.visit() or something like it for it to be part of the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess where your problem is. You should have a look at a sample implementation like the one on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example). As you will see there the pattern is not implemented by using extension but by using decorating interfaces.

Comment: I though that I don't have to implement the accept function in the Node class because I wasn't using it just the classes that extend it... I will try to implement it for Node but I'm worried that only that visitor will be called I mean visit(Node1 2 3 ) will never be called... I am quite confused... I know what the Visitor pattern does but I can't fully understand it.. thanks for the answers!

Comment: @IonelMerca: Actually you might not need the `Node` super class. Just let `Node1`, `Node2` and `Node3` implement the `VisitableNode` interface which has the method `accept(SomeVisitor)`. `SomeVisitor` has to have the methods `visit(Node1)`, `visit(Node2)` and `visit(Node3)`